# Correr Sitio web apache y nginx

Tags: php, mvc, apache, nginx

Tengo un sitio web con php, mysql, js, y patron mvc, corriendo sin inconvenientes en mi computador con apache.

El mismo sitio web en mi notebook con nginx, y solo entra en el index.php de configuración del sitio y el index del View con el formulario de login, ingreso los datos de acceso, y se queda ahí, no entra al sitio de administración.

Hay que hacer algo mas para que nginx reescriba las rutas o algo así, o hay que hacer un enrutador en php, no se que hacer. me pueden ayudar por favor.

.htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

nginx:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name syscon32.local;
   root /var/www/html/syscon32;

   index index.php;

   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?&args;
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
#        include fastcgi.conf;
#        include snippets/fastcgi.php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   }

   location ~ /\.ht {
       deny all;
   }

   error_log /var/log/nginx/syscon32_error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/syscon32_access.log;
}
```

Edite los archivos de error, error.log, syscon32_error.log, y estan vacios, tambien edite los archivos de acceso y en syscon32_access.log, encontre esto:
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2023:08:17:47 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1300 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gec>
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2023:08:17:47 -0300] "GET /Assets/img/logo-syscon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://syscon32.local/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux>
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2023:08:17:47 -0300] "GET /Assets/js/login.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://syscon32.local/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)>
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2023:08:18:10 -0300] "POST /Usuarios/validar/ HTTP/1.1" 404 187 "http://syscon32.local/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_6>

El inconveniente que encuentro es que no encuentra la ruta /Usuarios/validar/, La ruta existe

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Usuarios/validar/:1

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega los `.htaccess` del apache, y las configuraciones que tienes para el `NginX`, te sugiero que evites colocar las URL reales por motivos de seguridad.

Comment: agregué los códigos de los archivo htaccess y nginx

Comment: Apache y nginx parece estar correctos, ¿Tu sitio lo estas desplegando usando docker u otro sistema? o en cambio ¿Estas despliegando directamente el código en el servidor?

Comment: ¿Qué dicen los logs cuando quieres acceder a esa otra ubicación del sistema?

Comment: Agregué información en la consulta, Gracias